# Support "Open In supported Application" popover to open the file in another supported application - ipad

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios4

my application has all types of file, how i can handle to open files which are present in my application with supported application which are in my ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check out [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)